# BOOT_COMPLETED receiver doesn't work on Hisense device with Android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I'm working on application where I need to set alarm on reboot to start a service on specific interval.

I've created required Boot Complete Receiver class, added uses-permission and defined receiver in manifest file. I've tested on many real and simulated devices on every device, receiver works except Hisense device with Android 5.1.1

I've already tried these solutions.

[broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed)

[boot-completed-not-working-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android/46294732)

[android-boot-completed-not-received-when-application-is-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226410/android-boot-completed-not-received-when-application-is-closed/19856367#19856367)

I've also removed `android:installLocation="auto"` and added `android:directBootAware="true" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"` suggested in some thread.

Please find Receiver class and manifest code below.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Set instance Alarm on boot
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent messageCheckerIntent = new Intent(context, MessageCheckerService.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getService(context, REQ_MESSAGE_CHECK,
                        messageCheckerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Cancel if any existing alarm for given pendingIntent (MessageCheckerService)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        // Alarm is reset every time when this service is called,
        // still keep alarm repeating so if one call fails does not affect following calls
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                ALARM_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.project.myapp">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".GPSTrack" />

        <service
            android:name=".MessageCheckerService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried to put receiver into background service?

Comment: @ParthBhatti No, I've not put yet. But I don't understand what exactly I need to do for that. Have you a link with sample code which explains.