# Obtaining list of connected bluetooth low energy devices in android 3.1 and later

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on application which shows list of certain connected bluetooth low energy devices, so user can choose which one of them he wants to configure.

The problem is that [you can't just list all connected devices. As far as I know there are three possible ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716715/6505257):

1. Use [BluetoothProfiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getConnectedDevices(int))

   ```
    bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER);
   ```

   This fails because android won't connect to GATT server, when device connects, so device is neither under GATT_SERVER nor GATT profile. However once I call connectGatt method,

   ```
    bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
   ```

   device can be found under both GATT_SERVER and GATT profile. Other profiles are not supported by low energy devices.
2. List paired devices and try connectGatt on each of them

   ```
    List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    for(BluetoothDevice device : bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
         BluetoothGatt gatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
         if(gatt != null) {
             connectedDevices.add(device);
         }
         gatt.disconnect();
    }
   ```

   This method cannot be used as it cannot determine if device is already connected or only in range but not connected
3. On system boot start service listening to [ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) intents and maintaining list of connected devices

   Manifest

   ```
    <service android:name=".ManagerService" android:enabled="true" />
    <receiver
       android:name=".BootFinishedReceiver"
       android:directBootAware="true"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="false"
       android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

   Receiver

   ```
    public class BootFinishedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ManagerService.class);
              context.startService(serviceIntent);
         }
     }
   ```

   Service

   ```
    public class ManagerService extends Service {
         private static List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices;

         @Override
         public void onCreate() {
             connectedDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
             super.onCreate();
         }

         @Override
         public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
             IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
             filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
             filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
             registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, filter);
             return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
         }

         @Override
         public void onDestroy() {
             unregisterReceiver(connectionReceiver);
             super.onDestroy();
         }

         @Nullable
         @Override
         public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
             return null;
         }

         private final BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 String action = intent.getAction();
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                     connectedDevices.add(device);
                 }else{
                     connectedDevices.remove(device);
                 }
             }
         };

         public static List<BluetoothDevice> getConnectedDevices() {
             return connectedDevices;
         }
    }
   ```

   [Since 3.1 apps can no longer receive system intents before activity is started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19856367/6505257), so this cannot be used either.

**Is there any other way or how can I achieve it now in later android versions?**

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that [you can still use ON_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android/46294732#46294732), but you have to allow it in setting on your device. So my problem is solved